# Dropbox API v2 /delete in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dropbox-api

I'm learning about Dropbox API v2.

When I tried type the delete command, file was deleted successfully.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-delete

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/delete \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer <DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "{"path":"/test/memo.txt\"}"
```

When I tried to do same action in Google Apps Script,

```
function main() {
  var dropBoxAccessToken = "<DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN>"

  var dropBoxDeleteRes = JSON.parse(deleteDropBoxFiles(dropBoxAccessToken).getContentText())
  Logger.log(dropBoxDeleteRes)  
}

function deleteDropBoxFiles(apiKey) {
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/delete",
    {
      "method" : "post",
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      "payload" : {"path" : "/test/memo.txt"},
      "headers" : {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + apiKey},
      "muteHttpExceptions" : true // for debug
    }
  );
}
```

The error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token: E" was returned.
It would be great if anyone could help me.

Comment: It could be `JSON.parse` that's throwing the error. See what `getContentText` is returning before parsing it. I'm guessing that it's an error message that might be useful for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to JSON.stringify() your payload object as follows:

```
function deleteDropBoxFiles(apiKey) {
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/delete",
    {
      "method" : "post",
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      "payload" : JSON.stringify({"path" : "/test/memo.txt"}),
      "headers" : {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + apiKey},
      "muteHttpExceptions" : true // for debug
    }
  );
}
```